# How to unbake a cake?

Tags: baking, eggs, cake

I baked a cake and realized I added 1 less egg than I suppose to. I like to unbake the cake and add the egg. Then I like to bake it again. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Problem?

Comment: This sounds like an advertising campaign for the Norwegian yellow pages phone service called 1880: "We can help you with **almost** everything..." (with emphasis on the **almost** part)

Answer (score 10):

Can you start over? I'm pretty sure the baking process is non-reversible.